# Enumerações do Java são anti performáticas?

Tags: java, desempenho, kotlin, enums

Em um projeto pensei em trocar inteiros por `enum`s, mas um colega me falou que `enum`s são anti performáticos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, a enumeração do Java é uma classe, portanto um objeto mais pesado que um número puro e simples, e pior ainda, uma classe é alocada no *heap* que coloca pressão no *garbage collector*, como qualquer objeto colocado ali.

Porém não é que isso vai mudar demais as condições da sua aplicação, pelo menos em quase todas situações, pode existir algum caso fora da curva que seja relevante. Ao mesmo tempo, Java é "anti performático", seu colega falou isso?

Java não preza pela eficiência em tudo o que faz. Isso não quer dizer que Java seja lenta como alguns acham. Apenas ela não é uma linguagem preocupada ao extremo com eficiência. Ela consome memória como ninguém, então um `enum` a mais ou a menos não vai mudar muita coisa.

Será que você precisa dessa eficiência toda para esse caso? Se não precisa pode usar o `enum` mesmo que não seja nota 10, ainda será próximo disso. Se precisar da eficiência não use, mas duvido que seja o caso.

E veja se usar o `enum` tornará o código realmente mais legível, caso contrário também não precisa se preocupar. Eu não gosto do estilo que algumas pessoas usam ele escrevendo seus membros em ALL_CAPS.

Hoje é 8 ou 80, mas Java rumando mais à eficiência logo (apesar que estão prometendo há uns 5 anos) logo terá um tipo por valor personalizado que dará para simular um `enum` mais eficiente, quem sabe até criem um novo `enum` melhor. Hoje a solução 100% eficiente é usar um inteiro.

O `enum` do Java é mais que um `enum`, ele é bem poderoso, mas ineficiente na forma atual.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Esclareceu a dúvida que eu tinha.

Comment: `uma classe é alocada no heap que coloca pressão no garbage collector`. Por curiosidade, tem alguma referência (artigo/pergunta) que já mediu isso? Achei que `enum` era leve o suficiente para ser irrelevante a diferença.

Comment: Eu falo da irrelevância, mas não é zero.

Comment: Em Kotlin tudo é um objecto e portanto o uso do heap é inevitável. Esta discussão tem mais relevância para linguagens de mais baixo nível, por exemplo c++, ou go,  mas para linguagens como Java ou Kotlin, isto é muito menos relevante um vez que são liguagens com bases em conceitos de OOP, AOP e actualment FP. De notar que em Kotlin, apesar de tudo ser um objecto, várias estratégias foram implementadas para compensar possíveis pérdidas de performance com o tratar tudo como objectos.